# How to get Last 3 hours data from SQLite

Tags: android, sql, select, timestamp

I am inserting data in table with current system time like 
`System.currentTimeMillis()`. So, while getting data I need to take last 3 hours data only.

Following link not help me. because this link using specific date format which I don't have.
[Getting data according to last hours from sqlite](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33254848/getting-data-according-to-last-hours-from-sqlite)

Here Is my Query but seems it's not working.

```
SELECT * FROM Table1 where timestamp >= datetime('now','-3 hours')
```

Where timestamp is nothing but current system time while inserting.

Please give me any reference or hint.

Comment: Find the time millisecond of time that was 3 hours ago, then execute query to get the values with timestamp greater than this value.

Comment: if you want sqlite to give you a timestamp from the past, play a bit with `sqlite3` tool and execute the examples from [here](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_datefunc.html) and you will find that `SELECT strftime('%s','now');` is closest to what you want, the rest is your homework

Comment: Consider the timezone as well or the results might not be accurate 
`SELECT * FROM Table1 where datetime(timestamp) >=datetime('now', '-3 Hour', 'localtime');`
Please refer to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/381371/sqlite-current-timestamp-is-in-gmt-not-the-timezone-of-the-machine

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can get TimeStamp of Time 3 Hours back using following

```
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
cal.add(Calendar.HOUR, -3);
Date threeHourBack = cal.getTime();
```

Then you can pass `threeHourBack.getTime()` to the query.

Or You can do this in SQLite

```
SELECT * FROM Table1 where datetime(timestamp) >=datetime('now', '-3 Hour')
```

Comment: SELECT * FROM Table1 where datetime(timestamp) >=datetime('now', '-3 Hour') not working for me. I change it to     SELECT * FROM Table1 where datetime(timestamp, 'unixepoch') >=datetime('now', '-3 Hour')

Comment: This will select including the current hour, so not good.

Answer (score 0):

there could be other methods. but I think this will work for you.

```
 SELECT * FROM Table1 where timestamp >= (System.currentTimeMillis()-108000000)
```

subtract 3 hours from current time and and search for time grater than that.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
 SELECT * FROM Table1 where julianday(timestamp) >=  (julianday('now')-108000000)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
# https://www.sqlite.org/lang_datefunc.html
select DATETIME('now');                                  -- UTC time
select DATETIME('now', 'localtime');                     -- Local time
select DATETIME('now', 'localtime', '-5 hours');         -- Local time, but 5 hours ago
select DATETIME(0, 'unixepoch');                         -- 1970-01-01 00:00:00

select strftime('%s');                                   -- Current time in epoch UTC
select strftime('%s', '2022-07-01 00:00');               -- Converts to epoch UTC
select strftime('%s', '2022-07-01 00:00', 'localtime');  -- Converts to epoch
```