# How to add time to a timestamp in sqlite

Tags: sql, sqlite

I have two fields in my table : `last_service_date` and the `next_service_date`. The `last_service_date` has a default timestamp. What I want is to add 3 months to the `next_service_date`. Is that possible?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34283690/how-to-get-last-3-hours-data-from-sqlite

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [SQLite Date and Time Functions](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_datefunc.html)

Example of usage:

```
UPDATE tablename SET next_service_date=DATETIME(last_service_date , '+3 months');
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just run a simple sql command

```
UPDATE tablename SET next_service_date = last_service_date + (60*60*24*30*3);
```

That would do the job, but keep in mind that this piece of code changes every entry in the table! You may want to add a LIMIT to that.

Also, I assumed you wanted to add 3 months to the last_service_date. You may need to change that accordingly.

Some months may also have more or less than 30 days, which I used as a base.